# Custom Expandable List View with SimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Tags: android, binding, expandablelistview, simplecursoradapter

I have an `ExpandableListView` with `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`. In the childs, if I have no data, I need to display a loading `Spinner` and a `TextField`. However, when I have data, the data has to be displayed accordingly.
I have tried several things :-

1. I have created a new table , with first row having a textfield , which I have to display in case of empty data. (which also gives me the `Cursor`).
2. I have overridden `getChildView()`, `bindChildView()` functions.

Overriding the `getChildView()` function and creating a `View` inside it for a specific `Cursor` value, works just fine. However, after I return the newly created view, always the new view is binded, the old view is lost. Please tell me how to approach this problem.